# error using GroupBy in linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display same column value only once and for this i'm using linq `GroupBy` function but it is giving compile time error, I'm sharing my code please guide me thanks.

```
viewModel.TicketDetails = db.TicketDetails.OrderByDescending(c => c.TicketDetailId)
.Include(c => c.JunkPart).Include(c => c.Part).ToList()
.GroupBy(c => c.GenericOrderId).Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault());
```

The error is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i want to display same column value only once

Comment: I will go with moving the "ToList()" call to the last.

Comment: @Usama The downvote was likely because you didn't explain the problem and calling them a jerk probably won't help much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is returning a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Entities.TicketDetail>` but `viewModel.TicketDetails` is `ICollection<TiekctDetail>`. The error message tells you that.

Fix it with an explicit cast:

```
viewModel.TicketDetails = db.TicketDetails
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.TicketDetailId)
    .Include(c => c.JunkPart)
    .Include(c => c.Part).ToList()
    .GroupBy(c => c.GenericOrderId)
    .Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList(); //<--- Add this
```

Alternatively, you could change the type of `viewModel.TicketDetails` to `IEnumerable`

Comment: thanks it solved my issue, please vote up my question

Comment: Given that `IEnumerable` = lazy evaluation, changing the type of `viewModel.TicketDetails` to `IEnumerable` would most likely result in an exception saying that the database connection is closed (`db` is no longer in scope) when looping over it in the view. Converting to an array or list is therefore the right way.

Comment: Well it all depends on what you want to do with it so either option is valid. Given that the OP is using `Include` then the sensible solution is probably to use `ToList` but we don't really know the intention of the code here.